# Why can't I Write-Error from PowerShell.Streams.Error.add_DataAdded?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, runspace

I'm investigating using Runspaces for parallel running.  Currently, I'm trying to get back messages from whatever script I might run, to help me diagnose problems, in the same stream type from which they originate: verbose messages in the Verbose stream, etc.  So far, I can get Warning and Verbose messages but whenever I try to use Write-Error (or even just access ErrorRecord object properties) the console locks up.

There's a sample at the end of this which will demonstrate what I see.  Currently, the script produces four messages:

```
VERBOSE: This is a verbose message. 
WARNING: This is a warning message. 
System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord 
This is an error message.
```

If you uncomment any one of the comments in the `$ps1.Streams.Error.add_DataAdded({})` scriptBlock it locks up at that point.  Can anyone explain why and/or give me a workaround/fix?

I'm after something like this:

```
VERBOSE: This is a verbose message. 
WARNING: This is a warning message. 
C:\Work\me\PowerShell\Test-ReadPSDataStreams.ps1 : This is an error message.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\Test-ReadPSDataStreams.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Test-ReadPSDataStreams.ps1
```

This is the script:

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

$is1 = [InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault()

$rs1 = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace($is1)
$rs1.ApartmentState = 'STA'
$rs1.ThreadOptions = 'ReuseThread'
$rs1.Open()

$ps1 = [PowerShell]::Create()
$ps1.Runspace = $rs1
$ps1.Streams.Verbose.add_DataAdded({
    Param (
        [Object]$sender,
        [System.Management.Automation.DataAddedEventArgs]$e
    )

    foreach ($item in $sender.ReadAll()) {
        Write-Verbose $item.Message
    }
})

$ps1.Streams.Warning.add_DataAdded({
    Param (
        [Object]$sender,
        [System.Management.Automation.DataAddedEventArgs]$e
    )

    foreach ($item in $sender.ReadAll()) {
        Write-Warning $item.Message
    }
})

$ps1.Streams.Error.add_DataAdded({
    Param (
        [Object]$sender,
        [System.Management.Automation.DataAddedEventArgs]$e
    )

    foreach ($item in $sender.ReadAll()) {
        Write-Host $item.GetType()
        Write-Host $item.ToString()
        #Write-Host $item.ErrorDetails.Message
        #Write-Error 'test'
        #Write-Error $item.ToString()
    }
})

[void]$ps1.AddScript({ $VerbosePreference = 'Continue' })
[void]$ps1.AddScript({ Write-Verbose 'This is a verbose message.' })
[void]$ps1.AddScript({ Write-Warning 'This is a warning message.' })
[void]$ps1.AddScript({ Write-Error 'This is an error message.' })
$ps1.Invoke()
```

If there's another way of doing this, I'm open to it!

Comment: Don't really understand what you're doing or if this suffices, but `Write-Host $item.Exception.Message` inside your problem block seems to work

Comment: I'm doing it because otherwise these messages aren't presented to the developer (i.e. me) to help me debug.  What you've offered works but I was trying to get it into the error stream e.g. using Write-Error.  I'll clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

See if this is something that might help:

See if this helps:
http://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/invoke-scritptasync-v2/

If I'm reading the question correctly, it's designed for exactly the scenario you describe - testing scripts in a runspace environment and being able to write diagnostic information to the various output streams during execution, then retrieve that information after execution is finished and the runspaces disposed.

Comment: It isn't quite what I'm looking for.  I've ripped this out of the original code to avoid obscuring the issue.  I haven't replied previously because I'm still working through the implications of your code for my work.  I've upvoted, though, it because it has helped me.

Comment: What doesn't it do that you require?

Comment: I'm doing UI things with WPF and using the Runspace to run background threads to keep the UI responsive.  I've hit problems and I'm trying to get diagnostic stuff back to the main PowerShell session so I can see what's going wrong as it happens.

Comment: The function is made to write all the diagnostic stuff back to a hash table ($ResultHash) in the main session, so you can work on it from there.

Answer (score 2):

## Preface

I am writing this on my tablet, so please forgive me if the formatting doesn't come out right. It's especially important to note: my tablet keyboard doesn't have the back-tick character that PowerShell uses for its escape char; thus, I have written the newline sequence in the examples as "\n".

## My Solution

I played around with your technique, and this is what I observed:

(1) To work around the error stream not closing, access the background host's errors through its $Error variable instead. To do this use a synchronised hashtable as a SessionStateProxy to provide access to the background host's $Error; see example below.

```
→ $PRXY = [HashTable]::Synchronised(@{})

$rs1 = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
→ $rs1.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("PRXY",$PRXY)
$rs1.Open()

$ps1 = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
→  $PRXY.Error = $Error
    Write-Error "This is just a test from ps1"
})
$ps1.Runspace = $rs1
```

A good article about how to use synchronised hashtables with multi-threading can be found here:
http://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/19/sharing-variables-and-live-objects-between-powershell-runspaces/

## Other Things

(2) Using Write-Error to send the background runspace's error to the interactive console will overwrite the InvocationInfo of the error with the InvocationInfo of the Write-Error cmdlet.  Because of this I send the error object directly to the console output.

(3) Using event handlers gave me problems. As a work around I used Register-ObjectEvent and used event polling in a while loop to catch the messages from the background runspaces.

(4) Using stream.[type].ReadAll() with: warning, verbose and debug caused the host to hang in the same manner as trying to read from the error stream. To work around this I sent the stream content to a piped ForEach loop and then called the streams Clear() method.

## Full Example

Using two runspaces to demonstrate the concept. I would like to remind you again that this post was written from a tablet, so don't expect the example below to run without having to debug it first. When I get back to a real computer with the ISE, I will edit the below script to fix any syntax errors.

```
# Turn on verbose and debug messages
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
$DebugPreference = "Continue"

# Create background runspaces
$PRXY = [HashTable]::Synchronised(@{})

$rs = @()
For ($i = 0; $i -le 1; $i++)
{
    $rs += [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
    $rs[$i].SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("PRXY", $PRXY)
    $rs[$i].Open()
}

$sb1 = {
    $PRXY.PS1.Error = $Error
    $VerbosePreference = "Continue"
    $DebugPreference = "Continue"
    For ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++)
    {
        $msg = "Test [$i]"
        Write-Error $msg
        Write-Warning $msg
        Write-Verbose $msg
        Write-Debug $msg
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 750
    }
}
$sb2 = {
    $PRXY.PS2.Error = $Error
    $VerbosePreference = "Continue"
    $DebugPreference = "Continue"
    For ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++)
    {
        $msg = "Test [$i]"
        Write-Error $msg
        Write-Warning $msg
        Write-Verbose $msg
        Write-Debug $msg
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
    }
}
$PRXY.PS1 = @{}
$ps1 = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($sb1)
$ps1.Runspace = $rs[0]

$PRXY.PS2 = @{}
$ps2 = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($sb2)
$ps2.Runspace = $rs[1]

# Map event SourceIdentifiers to the runspace that produces the event
$EventRegister = @{}
$EventRegister.Error = @{}
$EventRegister.Warning = @{}
$EventRegister.Verbose = @{}
$EvevtRegister.Debug = @{}
$Registered = @()

# Register PS1 --------------------
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ps1.streams.error -EventName DataAdded
ForEach ( $id in (@(Get-EventSubscriber)).SourceIdentifier )
{
    If ( $id -notin $Registered )
    {
        $EventRegister.Error.Add($id, $ps1)
        $Registered += $id
    }
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ps1.streams.warning -EventName DataAdded
ForEach ( $id in (@(Get-EventSubscriber)).SourceIdentifier )
{
    If ( $id -notin $Registered )
    {
        $EventRegister.Warning.Add($id, $ps1)
        $Registered += $id
    }
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ps1.streams.verbose -EventName DataAdded
ForEach ( $id in (@(Get-EventSubscriber)).SourceIdentifier )
{
    If ( $id -notin $Registered )
    {
        $EventRegister.Verbose.Add($id, $ps1)
        $Registered += $id
    }
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ps1.streams.debug -EventName DataAdded
ForEach ( $id in (@(Get-EventSubscriber)).SourceIdentifier )
{
    If ( $id -notin $Registered )
    {
        $EventRegister.Debug.Add($id, $ps1)
        $Registered += $id
    }
}

# Register PS2 -----------------------
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ps2.streams.error -EventName DataAdded
ForEach ( $id in (@(Get-EventSubscriber)).SourceIdentifier )
{
    If ( $id -notin $Registered )
    {
        $EventRegister.Error.Add($id, $ps2)
        $Registered += $id
    }
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ps2.streams.warning -EventName DataAdded
ForEach ( $id in (@(Get-EventSubscriber)).SourceIdentifier )
{
    If ( $id -notin $Registered )
    {
        $EventRegister.Warning.Add($id, $ps2)
        $Registered += $id
    }
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ps2.streams.verbose -EventName DataAdded
ForEach ( $id in (@(Get-EventSubscriber)).SourceIdentifier )
{
    If ( $id -notin $Registered )
    {
        $EventRegister.Verbose.Add($id, $ps2)
        $Registered += $id
    }
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ps2.streams.debug -EventName DataAdded
ForEach ( $id in (@(Get-EventSubscriber)).SourceIdentifier )
{
    If ( $id -notin $Registered )
    {
        $EventRegister.Debug.Add($id, $ps2)
        $Registered += $id
    }
}

$hndl_ps1 = $ps1.BeginInvoke()
$hndl_ps2 = $ps2.BeginInvoke()

While ( !(hndl_ps1.IsCompleted) -or
        !(hndl_ps2.IsCompleted) )
{
    $Event = Wait-Event
    If ( $EventRegister.Error.ContainsKey($Event.SourceIdentifier) )
    {
        $psid = $EventRegister.Error[$Event.SourceIdentifier].InstanceId
        $stamp = "$psid::$($Event.TimeGenerated)"
        Write-Error $stamp
        If ( $psid -eq $ps1.InstanceId )
        {
          $PRXY.PS1.Error
          $PRXY.PS1.Error.Clear()
        }
        If ( $psid -eq $ps2.InstanceId )
        {
          $PRXY.PS2.Error
          $PRXY.PS2.Error.Clear()
        }
        Remove-Event -EventIdentifier $Event.EventIdentifier
        Continue
    }
    If ( $EventRegister.Warning.ContainsKey($Event.SourceIdentifier) )
    {
        $stamp = "$($EventRegister.Warning[$Event.SourceIdentifier].InstanceId::"
        $stamp += "$($Event.TimeGenerated)"
        $EventRegister.Warning[$Event.SourceIdentifier].streams.warning |
            ForEach {Write-Warning "{0}\n{1}\n\n" -f $stamp, $_}
        $EventRegister.Warning[$Event.SourceIdentifier].streams.warning.Clear()
        Remove-Event -EventIdentifier $Event.EventIdentifier
        Continue
    }
    If ( $EventRegister.Verbose.ContainsKey($Event.SourceIdentifier) )
    {
        $stamp = "$($EventRegister.Verbose[$Event.SourceIdentifier].InstanceId)::"
        $stamp += "$($Event.TimeGenerated)"
        $EventRegister.Verbose[$Event.SourceIdentifier].streams.verbose |
            ForEach {Write-Verbose "{0}\n{1}\n\n" -f $stamp, $_}
        $EventRegister.Verbose[$Event.SourceIdentifier].streams.verbose.Clear()
        Remove-Event -EventIdentifier $Event.EventIdentifier
        Continue
    }
    If ( $EventRegister.Debug.ContainsKey($Event.SourceIdentifier) )
    {
        $stamp = "$($EventRegister.Debug[$Event.SourceIdentifier].InstanceId)::"
        $stamp += "$($Event.TimeGenerated)"
        $EventRegister.Debug[$Event.SourceIdentifier].streams.debug |
            ForEach {Write-Debug "{0}\n{1}\n\n" -f $stamp, $_}
        $EventRegister.Debug[$Event.SourceIdentifier].streams.debug.Clear()
        Remove-Event -EventIdentifier $Event.EventIdentifier
        Continue
    }
}
$ps1.EndInvoke($hndl_ps1)
$ps2.EndInvoke($hndl_ps2)

# Optionally you can read the contents of all the streams after EndInvoke()
# to see if any messages were missed.
$ps1.streams.error
$ps1.streams.warning.ReadAll()
$ps1.streams.verbose.ReadAll()
$ps1.streams.debug.ReadAll()

$ps2.streams.error
$ps2.streams.warning.ReadAll()
$ps2.streams.verbose.ReadAll()
$ps2.streams.debug.ReadAll()

# Unregister subscribers if in the ISE
Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $_.SourceIdentifier
```

Answer (score 0):

To listen to the error stream, which appears to be special, you have to add your event listener **after** the runspace is started. That means you have to use asynchronous execution using `BeginInvoke()` and `EndInvoke()`.

```bsh
$block = { Write-Error "Some error message" }
$ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($block)
$asyncHandle = $ps.BeginInvoke()

$ret.powershell.Streams.Error.add_DataAdded({
  Param ( [Object]$sender, [System.Management.Automation.DataAddedEventArgs]$e )
  $sender.ReadAll() | % { Write-Error $_ }
})

while(!$ps.IsCompleted) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 25 }

try { $ps.EndInvoke($asyncHandle) }
finally { $ps.Dispose() }
```